# input is a int and variable is a string, I want a action if the string is greater that the int in the if statement. python3.8

Tags: python, if-statement

`input` is a int and variable is a string, I want a action if the string is greater than the int in the if statement. I'm using python 3.8

```py
name = input ("What is your name?")

print(name)

# print ("Yes or No")
age= input ("how old are you?")


if age >= 50:
    print (name, "You are looking good for your age!")
else:
    print(name, "You are getting old.")

print("Peace Out")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your input to int. The input will receive it as a string then you need to cast it to an int to be able to compare apples with apples

```
age = int(input("How old are you?"))
```

In python 3.8 you can also use the walrus operator (:= ). Your code will then look like this:

```
# Assign the value from input and print in 1 line thanks to :=    
print(name := input("What is your name?"))

# Make age an int and assign the value in your if statement with the walrus operator
if age := int(input("how old are you?")) >= 50:
    print (name, " You are looking good for your age!")
else:
    print(name, " You are getting old.")

print("Peace Out")
```

Peace out

Comment: thanks it worked fine with the with the walrus, not sure is i can use it, since school computers are still 2.7

Comment: Unfortunately not, this is a new operator introduced from python 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `age` variable to an `int` by using the `int()` when taking the input from the user.

```py
name = input ("What is your name?")

print(name)

# make the input an int
age= int(input("how old are you?"))

if age >= 50:
    print (name, "You are looking good for your age!")
else:
    print(name, "You are getting old.")

print("Peace Out")
```

Comment: Thanks helping a new guy, that was it

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `age` string to int and then check in the if statement.

```
age = int(input('How old are you?'))
```